# What is the opimal size of elasticserach object

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I am modeling data using elasticsearch for fast search.

I need to search JSON objects in the size of ~5MB (containing geo etc.)
There is no functional need to get partial data from this object - the application treats these object as an atomic unit.

I have the freedom to model it however i want to.
Is there a size consideration for storing objects?

Can i go with the approach of saving large objects or should i seperate these objects into smaller pieces and glue them after I query them?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you mostly need to return whole objects, it makes no sense to me to index them as smaller objects, retrieved them all, and then glue them into a single object in the client side. Just index them as an object and have something much simpler, less code, and probably more performant.

OTOH, if the object can be modeled after an parent/child relationship and you might need to query on the child objects etc, then of course go with modeling [it that way](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/mapping-parent-field.html)